# how to add a user in moodle and after add this user in a especifc course on Moodle using php

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I'm doing an integration between two systems, that from my system PHP i have to add a user on moodle, and after add this user on a especific course, i already knows the course id on moodle, i have no idea of how to do and begin that, so sorry for post no codes and exemples, on my server, the moodle's folder and my system's folder are in separated folders, I have seen many people with the same difficulty, so i believe that this question can help many peaple, someone know something about ?

Comment: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=173440

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the external database enrolment plugin

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/External_database_enrolment

You will need to enable the plug in first - click the eye icon to enable it

```
/admin/settings.php?section=manageenrols
```

Then you can change the settings for the external database

```
/admin/settings.php?section=enrolsettingsdatabase
```